# optimize search for timecode value in html5 video's buffer?

Tags: javascript, html, search, html5-video, binary-search

Here is my function for determining if a given timecode in the buffer of an html5 video element (learned about this [here](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/08/html5-video-buffered-property-available-in-firefox-4/)).

I think there must be a faster way.  Maybe a binary search over the start times?

I considered an interval tree, but the cost to maintain that data structure seems excessive given a system level data structure is provided.

```
isTimecodeInBuffer = function( _tc ) {
    var r = $(html5VideoEl).buffered;
    var i;
    var iMax = r.length;
    var within = false;

    //todo: better seek here
    for (i=0; i<iMax; ++i) {
        if (_tc >= r.start(i) && _tc < r.end(i)) {
            within = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return within;
};
```

Comment: What is `$(html5VideoEl).buffered`? Are you using a library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a standard binary search that is slightly modified to test for matching a time range, rather than an exact match. It's not worth storing any kind of data structure, since the data will change quite frequently as additional data is buffered.

```
function bufferedGreater(haystack, index, value) {
    return haystack.end(index) <= value;
}

function bufferedLess(haystack, index, value) {
    return haystack.start(index) > value;
}

function binarySearch(haystack, needle, greaterThan, lessThan) {
    var minIndex = 0,
        maxIndex = haystack.length - 1,
        currentIndex;

    while (minIndex <= maxIndex) {
        currentIndex = Math.floor((minIndex + maxIndex) / 2);
        if (greaterThan(haystack, currentIndex, needle)) {
            minIndex = currentIndex + 1;
        } else if (lessThan(haystack, currentIndex, needle)) {
            maxIndex = currentIndex - 1;
        } else {
            return currentIndex;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

var buffered = binarySearch(video.buffered, 10, bufferedGreater, bufferedLess) >= 0;
```

There is a working demo at http://jsbin.com/vifedogi/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Note: you'll want to access the `buffered` object directly on the video element, not on the jQuery object, like `var r = html5VideoEl.buffered;`